# Forward variable replacement

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

I have a string with variables that are replaced with the specified values via `replace` with `RegExp`.

How to implement it in such a way to avoid replacement of injected values with a different value when the original value happen to contain a variable name?

Example:

```
var s = format("$1, $2, $3", ["$2", "two", "three"]);
// returns: "two, two, three",
// needed: "$2, two, three"
```

How to implement such function `format` that would let us avoid replacement of previously injected values that happen to have a recognizable variable in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.replace(callback)` is the simplest option:

```js
function format(str, args) {
  return str.replace(/\$(\d+)/g, function(_, idx) {
    return args[idx - 1];
  });
}

var s = format("$1, $2, $3", ["$2", "two", "three"]);
document.write(s)
```